# Convergence of $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Upon research I know this series diverges because of the comparison test but I do not know what to compare the series to as I am having trouble finding a series smaller that diverges. And I know when I use the comparison test, my comparison series will diverge because of the $p$-series test.

Answer (score 3):

Try multiplying the top and the bottom by $\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}$. After simplifying we get
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n+1})}=\frac{1}{2(n+1)}$$

Comment: That's where I get stuck at. After multiplying by the conjugate I get

$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+n}\:$

Comment: @user196606 Please see my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

We have (since $\log x$ is a concave function on $(1,\sqrt{2})$):
$$\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}-1\geq\frac{1}{2}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) $$
hence:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}}\geq\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{\log(N+1)}{2}.$$

Answer (score -1):

If you are stuck, I'd try doing a little algebra first. Note that $$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}} = \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}} \\ = \sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n}}-1 $$ Now you can compare $$\sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n}}-1 \geq \sqrt{\frac{0+1}{n}}-1 \\ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-1$$ and hence $$-1+\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Comment: This is wrong. Or rather it is correct, but the final term diverges to negative infinity: that 1 is present in every term of the infinite series, you can't pull it out. So all you've proven is that the sum is greater than or equal to negative infinity, which is useless.

Comment: @dco84612 I'll rewrite it, but the $-1$ is intended to be outside the bounds of the sum. Pardon me for making useless statements!

Comment: I'm saying you can't simply take it out of the sum: Look how you have constructed your series; each individual TERM is greater than $1/sqrt(n)-1$: so you have all those 1s inside your series. what you have proven is that the square root is strictly greater than a negative number for each term.